# How to read parameters from view file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, query-string

I have a route:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/professor?roles=1
```

Now In my view file I have a checkbox, and I want to check if roles = 1 I want checkbox to be checked, if not, it must be unchecked.

I tried this:

```
<input type="checkbox" <%=  (!@roles.blank? && !@roles.include?(0) ? " checked='checked' " : "") %> />
```

No errors, but it's not working.

Comment: Does `params[:roles]` work?

Comment: @Stefan yes, it does and it returns correct value. I even tried    roles = params[:roles] but then I get fixnum to string error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query parameters are available in the `params` hash:

```
# http://127.0.0.1:3000/professor?roles=1
params[:role] #=> "1"
```

Note that the values are strings.

There's also a [`check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag) helper:

```
<%= check_box_tag nil, nil, params[:role] == "1" %>
```

You could also set an instance variable in your controller action:

```
def index
  @role = params[:role].to_i
  # ...
end
```

and use that in your view instead:

```
<%= check_box_tag nil, nil, @role == 1 %>
```